# How to get all the data of a report in BI using REST API?

Tags: rest, business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a report created using query in SAP BI launchpad, now I want to get all the data in the report created using GET method from advanced REST client.

To request the URL with GET method, what are the parameters to be given to get all the data of a report?

Base URL: `http://<server_name>:6405/biprws/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either retrieve the data of a report or the data of a dataprovider (ie: a query).

**Retrieving data from a dataprovider** (you will need 3 calls for non trivial document):

*Getting the list of dataproviders*

```
[GET] http://<hostname>:6405/biprws/documents/<documentID>/dataproviders
```

*Getting the flow count of dataproviders* (could be more than 1 in case of incompatible objects; when there are contexts in the query).

```
[GET] http://<hostname>:6405/documents/<documentID>/dataproviders/DP0/flows/count
```

*Getting the data of a flow*:

```
[GET] http://<hostname>:6405/documents/<documentID>/dataproviders/DP0/flows/0
```

---

**Retrieving data from a report**

*Getting the list of reports in a document*

```
[GET] http://<hostname>:6405/documents/<documentID>/reports
```

*Export the content of the report as CSV*

```
[GET] http://<hostname>:6405/documents/<documentID>/reports/<reportID>
```

Send this last request with an `Accept` header equals to `text/csv`

---

[For more information, you should have a look to the online documentation](https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/7da2e2d66f701014aaab767bb0e91070.html).

Comment: I don't want to export but get the result in a Json format @Arnaud Develay

Comment: So I think you need to use the DataProviders APIs, but JSON is not available. You have only csv or xml format.

Comment: isn't it possible to get data of a report in JSON format with any restapi? @Arnaud Develay

Comment: You can try the Semantic Layer REST API, which allows to retrieve the result of a Query in JSON. But it is not based on Web Intelligence document, you will have to build and execute a query each time. Documentation can be found here: https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/ec54c88f6fdb101497906a7cb0e91070.html

Comment: base url for semantic layer  http://<server_name>:6405/biprws/sl/v1. What is s1,v1 ? @Arnaud Develay

Comment: it is SL, not S1. V1 was added in case of breaking changes in the API (which have never occurred). Take these path parameters as the root URL of the service since they will never change.

Comment: http://servername:6405/biprws/sl/v1 when i send request using GET method, i get                                                                                                   `{
"error_code": "RWS 00056",
"message": "Not found. (RWS 00056)"
}` Why am i getting a not found error? @Arnaud Develay

Comment: Quite simple: this endpoint is not defined. You can try one of these (after a successful login of course), http://servername:6405/biprws/sl/v1/universes or http://servername:6405/biprws/sl/v1/queries. Good luck.

Comment: Note that the export of data from an SL query will be in OData format, not JSON.

Comment: if not query,I want to retrieve data of a report in JSON format @Joe

Comment: Information given by you is helpful but if its not a query, a report in BI, web intelligence report and i want to retrieve data of the report ?@ArnaudDevelay

Comment: So, I have already answered to your request. Check my answer, get data at dataprovider level or at report level (you can even drill to reportelement, to retrieve data from a specifix table for example). But we don't support JSON output for now. You will have to work with XML or another supported text format.

Comment: @Joe, there is a JSON output also : https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/ec54ce1d6fdb101497906a7cb0e91070.html

Comment: @ArnaudDevelay what do you mean by But it is not based on Web Intelligence document, you will have to build and execute a query each time in your earlier replies ?

Comment: Semantic Layer REST API allows to create Queries on top of universes (unv or unx). These Queries are only available during your session lifecycle. It means that when your session is closed, the Queries are deleted and you have to rebuild them in order to retrieve data. If you need to work with a Web Intelligence document directly (which offer more capabilities such as advanced formulas, multi dataproviders, ...), you have to use the Web Intlligence REST API.

Comment: @ArnaudDevelay can you look at this question                                                    https://stackoverflow.com/q/44304507/7851140